# Java equivalence to php hash

Tags: java, php, hash, md5, sha256

I am trying to get a api working in java, but I am having a hard time trying to get the hash for the password correct. In PHP this works -  hash('sha256', md5("password")) - what is the java equivalence to that? I have tried DigestUtils.sha256Hex(DigestUtils.md5("password")) but it does not result in the same hash.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you use `DigestUtils.sha256Hex(DigestUtils.md5Hex("password"))`? Also, don't use fast hashes for passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I got it. I had to use DigestUtils.md5Hex not DigestUtils.md5